# Vertical alignment html element

Tags: html, css

I put image inside div->td element to show just below header.

Fiddle : [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/Lx9cS/1/)

```
 <body>
        <div class="page-header header">
            <h1 class="page-header-text">thenwat</h1>
        </div>
            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <div class="left">
                        <td style="width:15%" valign= "top">

                            <div class="media">
                                <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="Profile pic">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </div>
                    </tr>
                </table>
<body>
```

But it show small space between header and image. what is it?

Comment: What is your expected result. There is an line between header and image, what about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that  it's just a margin of your `.header`.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx9cS/4/)

**CSS**

```
.header{margin-bottom:0}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove all tables its not good practice 
use div/li

set parent div style     **'display:table'**
and set child div style   **display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;**

Answer (score 1):

your `.page-header` is having margin. remove that.

```
.page-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
   /* margin: 40px 0 20px;*/
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given margin in `.page-header`. You can change`.page-header` css or overwrite css as you `.header` class already there

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx9cS/8/)

Comment: it not the case, I checked. padding does not affect here

Answer (score 0):

in youre css you find a css class named .page-header

your code looks like

```
.page-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    margin: 40px 0 20px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

you just replace with

```
.page-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    margin: 40px 0 0;
}
```

i think it should work that you want

Answer (score 0):

`.page-header` is having margin. give `margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugw5h/)**

```
<div class="page-header header" style="margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same code means just try line-height css in your tag